# Guzzle Http Not Logging In Laravel With Monolog

Tags: laravel, middleware, monolog, guzzle

I have this example:

```php
use Monolog\Logger;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use GuzzleHttp\MessageFormatter;

    public function getApiTest()
    {

        $stack = HandlerStack::create();
        $stack->push(
            Middleware::log(
                new Logger('Logger'),
                new MessageFormatter('{req_body} - {res_body}')
            )
        );

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(
            [
                'base_uri' => 'http://apitesting.test/api/',
                'handler' => $stack,
            ]
        );

        echo (string) $client->get('apitest')->getBody();
    }
```

Which should be logging the request and response, from what I understand.

I have a custom logging channel built for logging to the database instead.. But I have now disabled it and went back to Laravel's file logging - but this is still not logging the Guzzle request/response.

Comment: The Logger in your example doesn't have any handlers, so it doesn't know where to send log information. You also say you "went back to Laravel's file logging", but you haven't hooked into Laravel at all in your code example. Is this the code you're using? If not, you should update your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the first parameter of the `Middleware::log()` is suppose to be the log channel that you are trying to use. For example:

```php
$stack = HandlerStack::create();

$logChannel = app()->get('log')->channel('my-custom-channel');

$stack->push(
    Middleware::log(
        $logChannel,
        new MessageFormatter('{req_body} - {res_body}')
    )
);
```

That will tell the middleware which log channel that you are trying to use.

Comment: This solved my problem thanks. Setting the channel in the logger instance e.g `new Logger("channel-name")` was logging to the terminal instead of the specified file in `config/logging`.